# Elasticsearch point in polygon query

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial, spatial, elastic-stack, spatial-query

i'm using `Elasticsearch V6.7.1.`

I have created few indices and filled them with data. each index has a field 
`gps_coords` with `lat and`lon` values ( coordinates )

What I want to do is to write a query, where i pass a polygon and check if a certain point falls into that polygon, is that possible ?

This is a query that I've already tried:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
             "filter": {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "location": {
                        "shape": {
                            "type": "polygon",
                            "coordinates" : [
                                [25.0245351, 54.5693374], 
                                [25.0245351, 54.83232],
                                [25.4815808, 54.83232],
                                [25.4815808, 54.5693374],
                                [25.0245351, 54.5693374]
                              ]
                        },
                        "relation": "within"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "Invalid LinearRing found. Found a single coordinate when expecting a coordinate array"
      }
    ],
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "Invalid LinearRing found. Found a single coordinate when expecting a coordinate array"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Here is my index mapping:

```
[
            'index' => 'places',
            'body' => [
                'mappings' => [
                    'place' => [
                        "properties" => [
                            "gps_coords" => [
                                "ignore_malformed" => true,
                                "type" => "geo_shape"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],

                ],
                "number_of_replicas" => 0
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

can someone please point me to the right direction.

Thank you !

Comment: This is because your mapped field name is `gps_coords` NOT `location`. Change your query to be a `geo_shape` query against the field `gps_coords`

Answer (score 3):

First, in the query sample you use `location` field instead of `gps_coords`, as already stated in the comment. But I believe this is just a typo because that's not the source of the error.

The reason you receive a parse exception is that you are missing one pair of brackets in the polygon definition in `geo_shape` query. See the correct form [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/geo-shape.html#_ulink_url_http_www_geojson_org_geojson_spec_html_id4_polygon_ulink). The correct form would be (just the relevant part):

```
"shape": {
    "type": "polygon",
    "coordinates" : [
        [[25.0245351, 54.5693374], 
         [25.0245351, 54.83232],
         [25.4815808, 54.83232],
         [25.4815808, 54.5693374],
         [25.0245351, 54.5693374]]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tomas. Really saved my day. I was missing the pair of brackets:D

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sorry, my bad, just copied the example from ES docs not my code. Okey, will try to add those brackets and see if it helps, thanks!